# How to switch focus in different modals and html pafes when I minimize a modal using jquery

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using http://www.jquery-az.com/minimize-maximize-modal-of-bootstrap-by-using-jquery-3-demos/ to minimize a bootstrap modal in my angular application.

The issue using this plugin is whenever I minimize a modal then I am not able to do anything on the any html page like typing something in input box, scrolling the page etc.

What is the solution to fix this issue?

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Please add fiddle

Answer (score 0):

may be this is because the font-awesome css file is not getting loaded properly.

I have replaced the existing link tag with the below one and it is working for me.

```
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I believe this will solve your issue